# React Native error on react-native run-android

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run a React Native Project and it's throwing the following error on react-native run-android.

I have a RN project for version 0.60.4 , to upgrade to version 0.63.3 I created a new project with version 0.63.3 and copied all the files from old project RN Version 0.60.4 to new RN project with version 0.63.3.

After doing the above step its throwing the following error.

Can anyone please help me out as why the issue exists.

Following are the logs:

```
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.331]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.332]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/Interstitial.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.332]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/RewardedVideo.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.333]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/Reference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/SyncTree.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/Reference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.334]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.334]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.334]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/CollectionReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/Query.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/QuerySnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentChange.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/CollectionReference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.335]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.335]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/FieldValue.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.336]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/functions/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.336]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/reference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/task.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.337]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/FAB/FAB.js -> node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/FAB/FABGroup.js -> node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/FAB/FAB.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.337]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/Appbar/Appbar.js -> node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/Appbar/AppbarHeader.js -> node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/Appbar/Appbar.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.337]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/ToggleButton/ToggleButton.js -> node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/ToggleButton/ToggleButtonGroup.js -> node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/ToggleButton/ToggleButton.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.338]  ERROR    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Animated.Text.propTypes.style')
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.338]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
[Wed May 05 2021 17:04:41.339]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "FunnyAppName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@yfuks/react-native-action-sheet": "^0.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-appstore-version-checker": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-check-version": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-complete-flatlist": "^1.1.34",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.5.2",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-dropdown": "^0.0.6",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^3.7.8",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
    "react-native-flip-toggle-button": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-floating-action": "^1.21.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-hr": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.3.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-multiple-choice": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.3",
    "react-native-multiple-select-list": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-razorpay": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-select-contact": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-select-multiple": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-selectme": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.3",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-textarea": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-version-info": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-web-swiper": "^1.16.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^7.5.2",
    "react-native-youtube": "^2.0.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.16",
    "rn-multiple-choice": "^0.0.5",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Your error seems linked to a style props passed to an `<Animated.Text>` component, please provide the code of your components so that we can help further!* - [Mickaël Gagné](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8649680/micka%c3%abl-gagn%c3%a9).

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
// import RNFetchBlob from '../index.js'
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
const RNFetchBlob = NativeModules.RNFetchBlob
```

Comment: Hey there! @reza
could you please explain how this is working and why RNFetchBlob from rn-fetch-blob is replaced with this?

Comment: Hello @SheshNarayanDeshmukh , I only made a formatting edit to this answer, Dyego is the person you could actually answer your question.

Comment: Hey @DyegoTavaresLima!!
could you please explain this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed on the [Github page](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/183). You need to remove or comment the  import line

```
// import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
```

After it, you need to import NativeModules from the react-native and call the package by using NativeModules

```
const RNFetchBlob = NativeModules.RNFetchBlob;
```